# how to get absolute virtual addresses in Global Offset Table

Tags: linux, x86, g++, elf, dynamic-linking

after compiling code, my function(function name: overwriteFunc, symbol: _ZN4test13overwriteFuncEiml@plt).
It seems like I have address in Procedure Linkage Table. Then is there a way I could find my function absolute virtual address in Global offset table? Should I read some segment of private table of some .so, elf file?

Thanks

Comment: http://xyproblem.info -- what is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: The real problem is that I want to get the real absolute virtual address of function instead of address in Procedure Linkage Table. is there any way to do so？